# Using Android seeker with MVVM and data binding

Tags: android, seekbar

quick question for you all. In my application, I am using MVVM with data binding. I am trying to implement a seekbar but am having trouble deciding where to handle the SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener methods (onProgressChange, onStartTracking, onStopTracking). Would this be considered view logic and should the listener just be implemented in the view and then the results passed back to the view model? Or is there a more clean way of doing this? I am also aware that I can do this to set the initial value of the seekbar but can I use it to listen for callbacks?

```
android:progress="@{viewModel.progress}"
```

Thanks!